# Why does alert box shows twice?

Tags: angular, typescript

Whenever I run this code alert box pops-up twice

```
<p *ngIf="serverCreated;else noServer">{{alertBox(Success)}}</p>

<ng-template #noServer>
   <p>{{alertBox(Failed)}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: where do you write serverCreated in .ts file ?  i guess the problem is you set "serverCreated= true"  twice in your .ts file

Comment: do you aware about angular Lifecycle Hooks ? may be you set "serverCreated= true" in wrong lifecycle

Comment: it's not a "good idea" call a function in .html. I think that first the function is evaluated and then try to display the result. Why do your component not implement OnInit and in the ngOnInit call to the function?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your html code like that

```
<p *ngIf="serverCreated===true;then serverCreated===false">{{alertBox(Success)}}</p>
<ng-template #noServer>
   <p>{{alertBox(Failed)}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

and set serverCreated property `Nullable<boolean>` in your .ts file,

```
serverCreated? = null;
```

and when you want success alert,you can set `createdServer=true`

Comment: I changed code like this and else part only triggered and Other components also hidden from viewPort

Comment: Ofcourse, because serverCreated was false.What do you want ?

Comment: alert box pops-up infinitely, I'm not able to give input.

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned now alert box not shown even the task has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing `ifelse` just check whether `serverCreated` param created or not, in this way we cannot see two times alert box

```
<span *ngIf="serverCreated===true">
    <p *ngIf="serverCreated;else noServer">
     {{alertBox(Success)}}
    </p>
</span>

<ng-template #noServer>
       <p>{{alertBox(Failed)}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy I think you have resolved this issue but I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your else should be inside the *ngIf directive. Check below example for details

```
<div class="lessons-list" *ngIf="lessons else loading">
  ... 
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
    <div>Loading...</div>
</ng-template>
```

Your code should be

```
<p *ngIf="serverCreated else noServer">{{alertBox(Success)}}</p>
<ng-template #noServer>
   <p>{{alertBox(Failed)}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Hope that helps